# REGEX, find the "]"

Tags: regex

I use REGEX. 
How can I find the "]" symbol?

I tried `[\]]` but this does not work, because it searches the "`\`" instead....

**PS.**
I use EditPlus as text editor, and use the "regular expressions" option in that software to find occurences, not a programming language, so maybe is a bug, but what should be the correct query?...

**PPS.**
I need to replaces all `[` or `]` chars by empty char "". So I use `[\\]]|[\\]]`, but this does not work...

Comment: What are you using to find the bracket? Java? A .NET language? An editor?

Comment: the original question was very misleading because it was tagged 'java' and '.net' while the problem occurred using the EditPlus text editor.

Comment: @bw_üezi: I used Java and .NET to take attention to the people from .NET and JAVA, because I believe they could be familiar with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the regexp `\[|\]`

Comment: “Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.” Leonardo da Vinci

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a character class if you're looking for just one character. Try this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\]");
```

Edit: Oh, so you're not using Java, you're using an editor. Well then, try `\]` or simply `]` (which should compile to `\]` because in this context it can only mean a literal bracket).

Edit 2: So now your question is "How do I match opening or closing brackets?". OK, that does call for a character class.

Many regex engines allow `[][]` to mean "any character present in the list  `],[`". If your editor doesn't, try `[\]\[]`.

Comment: I need to replaces all [ or ] chars by empty char "". So I use `[\\]]|[\\]]`, but this does not work...

Comment: @moldovanu: How about editing the question to reflect your actual problem instead of confusing us by adding crucial details one bit at a time?

Answer (score 0):

In java you have to write `"[\\]]"`

For example this test returns `true`.

```
String s = "]val";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\]]val");
System.out.println("match: " + p.matcher(s).matches());
```

If you need to replaces all `[` or `]` chars by empty char "" write

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

Comment: this should find `\]` occurences..., but not just `]`

Comment: No, because the char `'\'` is a Java string escaping char. So when you write `"[\\]]"` java create a string with content `"[\]]"`.

Comment: Did you at least try the suggestion?

Comment: dash, be attentive, I find the CLOSING bracket, not the opening one!

Comment: I don't understand...  because the char '\' is a Java string escaping char, so `\\`` should give a "\" as output..., but `\]` the `]`...

Comment: Example, if you want to create a java string that contains " you have to write `"\""`. \ is the escaping char and every time it appears in the string it escape the next char. So in java if you want to put the char "\" in a string you have to write `"\\"`.

Comment: Ok I add an example to replace all [ and ] in a string.